# Database structure for messaging system

Tags: php, mysql, database, schema

I am trying to develop a messaging system for use by users in a school management system. There are different "user types", such as teachers, students, parents etc. I want users to be able to send messages to a single user and also a group (multiple users). This is my current database structure. Is this an acceptable design? How can I improve on this?

messages table:

```
id | msg_subject | msg_content | msg_timesent
```

messages_map table:

```
msgid | sender_ID | receiver_ID
```

Comment: That seems fine. Nice use of primary/foreign keys, by the way.

Comment: Is `msgid` meant to be a foreign key referencing `messages.id` ? Also, how would you differentiate if the message was sent to a single user or a group? Or will you have a message for each member of the group?

Comment: Yes, msgid references messages.id. I was thinking adding the same message for each member of the group. I am still not sure how to do this with PHP (running the same INSERT query but cycling through a bunch of receiver_ID). Is there a better way?

Comment: @Bruno that's the way to insert multiple entries in a db (wrap them in a transaction). MySQL also allows you to do `INSERT INTO messages_map (msgid,sender_ID,receiver_ID) VALUES (1,1,1) , (1,1,2) ...` but that's not standard SQL syntax which means your app will only work with MySQL

Comment: you need also receiver table  id | msg_destination , msg_destination means it will be send to single or group

Comment: @apokryfos Oh I see, I intend to only use it with MySQL so I think i'll go ahead with that method.

Comment: @TowfikAlrazihi I don't understand :/

Comment: @TowfikAlrazihi the receiver_ID in the messages_map works equally well for that purpose. That's why I asked how the single to group messages would be differentiated.

Comment: @apokryfos but how to differentiate between group and single if you don't have a receiver table

Comment: @TowfikAlrazihi If a single `msgid` has mutliple `receiver_ID` in the `messages_map` table, then it's a group message otherwise its a single message.

Comment: @Bruno , mysql method is a little bit diffrent, I mean for each switch in purpose, You need a table for that ! this always works for me

Comment: @Bruno it occurs to me that you can move the sender_ID to the messages table since a message has a single sender (right?)

Comment: @apokryfos You're right! Then the messages_map table would have the receiver_id and I can perhaps add a timestamp to indicate whether it's been read or not.

Comment: @TowfikAlrazihi I am very much a beginner so for now I only know the very basic ways to accomplish something lol, so I think for now i'll stick to this method, I appreciate your help anyway :)